# CakePHP AppController afterFilter variable inheritance weirdness

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

I don't get why the variables are not changed in the AppController. I have a subclass of AppController and in the action method, I am changing a variable of AppController. However this does not get reflected in the afterFilter.

This is CakePHP's AppController

```
<?php

class AppController extends Controller {

    var $xxxx;

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->xxxx = 'this should be changed';
    }

    function afterFilter()
    {
        var_dump($this->xxxx);
        exit;
    }


}
?>
```

And this is my UsersController

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController {


    function view( $id )
    {
        echo "From the AppController: {$this->xxxx} \n";
        $this->xxxx = 'with this';
    }

}
?>
```

This is the output when I run it:

```
From the AppController: this should be changed
string 'this should be changed' (length=22)
```

I am expecting this:

```
From the AppController: this should be changed
string 'with this' (length=9)
```

Do you know why it behaves this way? Any pointers how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use beforeRender() instead of afterFilter().

[Request Life-cycle callbacks](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#request-life-cycle-callbacks) will surely help you to achieve the same.

Kindly ask if it not worked for you.

Comment: This worked. I am still wondering why the subclass variables are missing from afterFilter...

Comment: That is because of beforeFilter() method was executed before the controller's action execution. So to execute your controller's view() method, beforeRender() callback will be executed just before the page will be rendered. I hope you get understand the reason now.